# Robot Framework - Search for text in WebTable

Tags: robotframework

Below is the cssselector and xpath

```
#ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__0 > td:nth-child(3)
//*[@id="ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__0"]/td[3]
```

This is part of a WebTable and I want to search for a text in the table

The increment is below

```
#ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__1 > td:nth-child(3)
//*[@id="ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__1"]/td[3]

#ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__2 > td:nth-child(3)
//*[@id="ctl00_MasterContentPlaceHolder_radGridSystemRoles_ctl00__2"]/td[3]
```

How can I search each row in the table to find the text?

Answer (score 0):

The XPath is just a string, so you can customize it to get the particular row.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


Test Teardown  Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}           Chrome
${URL}               https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/
${TEXT TO SEARCH}    The Irishman (2019)
${NUMBER OF COLUMN}  ${3}
${NUMBER OF ROWS}    ${15}


*** Test Cases ***
Test search in table
    Open Browser  url=${URL}
    ...           browser=${BROWSER}
    ${found flag}=  Set variable  ${False}
    FOR  ${row number}  IN RANGE  1  ${NUMBER OF ROWS}
    ${field locator}=  Get field XPath  ${row number}
    Log  ${field locator}
    ${field text}=  Get text  ${field locator}
    Log  ${field text}
    ${found flag}=  Set variable if  '${field text}'=='${TEXT TO SEARCH}'
    ...                              ${True}
    ...                              ${found flag}
    END
    Should be true  ${found flag}
    ...             msg=Movie '${TEXT TO SEARCH}' is not found in the table
    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Get field XPath
    [Arguments]  ${row number}
    ${xpath}=    Set variable  //table[@class='table']//tbody/tr[${row_number}]/td[${NUMBER OF COLUMN}]
    [Return]     ${xpath}
```

Here I've used a template for the XPath of particular field of table: `//table[@class='table']//tbody/tr[${row_number}]/td[${NUMBER OF COLUMN}]`, where `${row_number}` is a row number I get from the for-loop.

Seems to be useful for your case.